# Android Storage path not the same on devices?

Tags: java, android, storage

Hej community!
I want to read mp3 files from the storage of the device using `File = Environment.getexternaldirectory()` or something like this.
I get a null pointer exc. when I try to get Files from there. In my phone I looked up the path of a file in a file explorer. It said storage\emulated\0 same as in my code. So, what is wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: A file explorer app, or DDMS file explorer?  On recent devices, DDMS (and ADB on which it depends) actually sees the external storage **at a different mount point** than apps see it at - yes, on a given device, **the path can actually be different depending on "who" is asking**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this method to retrieve a List of files.

```
public List<File> getMP3Files(String directory) {
    List<File> files = new ArrayList<File>();
    File folder = new File(directory);
    for (File file : folder.listFiles()) {
        if (file.isFile()) {
            if (file.getName().endsWith(".mp3") || file.getName().endsWith(".MP3")) {
                files.add(file);
            }
        }
    }
    return files;
}
```

for example if you have your .mp3 files located in: "/storage/emulated/0",  you only need.

```
String directoryPath=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath(); // path /storage/emulated/0/                  
List<File> list = getMP3Files(directoryPath);
```

If you have your .mp3 in other location, for example i have my .mp3 files in: "/storage/emulated/0/Music/Overkill"

```
 String mp3Directory = "/Music/Overkill";
 String directoryPath=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + mp3Directory; 
 List<File> list = getMP3Files(directoryPath); 

//print in LogCat the list of .mp3:
for (File file : list) {     
        Log.i("MP3 File name", file.getName());
    }
```

Comment: I try this:
list = getMP3Files(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory());
Then in the getMP3Files:
File[] files = Directory.listFiles(new MP3FileNameFilter());
After that files = null

Comment: Do you know where are located your mp3 files, for example i have my mp3 files in "/storage/emulated/0/Music/Overkill"

Comment: I copied some tracks in /storage/emulated/0. At least the explorer shows that to me.